# How to run current line in Spyder 3.5( ctrl +f10 not working)

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

I am very new to Python and I am used to R studio so I choose Spyder. On the Spyder layout I saw a button 'run current line (ctrl +f10)'. But it doesn't work by pressing the button or c+10. Am I missing something? I can only select the script and 'ctrl+enter ' to run current line which is not convenient at all. I am using ubuntu with Anaconda distribution.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The key to run the current line by itself is `F9`. The shortcut `ctrl+F10` is used if you are in debugging mode.

You can see a list of shortcuts by selecting `Preferences` in the `Tool` menu, and then clicking on `Keyboard shortcuts`.

Comment: In Spyder 3.3.6, on 2 different machines running _Windows 10_, _F9_ does not work for me but selecting the menu option _Run selection or current line_ does.
Also, selecting the text and clicking _Ctrl+Return_ does work however!

Answer (score 25):

Coming from R studio I imagine you were hoping to have a command that runs the next command, rather than just that one row (which can break a command into several parts and cause errors).

The exact equivalent doesn't exist yet but if you get accustomed to adding **#%%** before and after chunks (**"cells"**) you want to run together then you can use the following commands to run the whole chunk.

Run cell: **Ctrl + Return**
Run cell and advance : **Shift+Return**

Comment: This answer was very useful as it gave context information from some coming from RStudio using Rnotebooks to Spyder for similar functionality.

Answer (score 6):

`F9` is the key that does the job for you. 
To replicate the RStudio style, go to `Preferences` in `Tools` menu and go to `Keyboard Shortcuts`.

Since `Ctrl + Enter` is assigned to another function, change that first.
Then assign the `F9` key value to `Ctrl + Enter`. Now Spyder is the same as RStudio. Atleast in a way.

Answer (score 2):

Some keyboards have a different layout than others in terms of what the keys are supposed to do. For me running happens if done via `Fn + F9`.

Answer (score -1):

Control Enter is a quick way of executing a line or block of code in both R Studio & Python.

In Spyder, make sure the line or block is highlighted before you hit 'ctrl-enter'