# Run current line in Spyder 3.3.3 not working

Tags: spyder

The shortcut keys to run the current line and advance (Shift+Return) in Spyder is not working.  I have checked the preferences and the binding I want is there.  Any suggestions on why Shift+Return is not working?  I am using Spyder 3.3.3 on Windows 78 (64 bit).

The soluitions here:

[How to run current line in Spyder 3.5( ctrl +f10 not working)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39031796/how-to-run-current-line-in-spyder-3-5-ctrl-f10-not-working)

are not working for me.  My preference settings are below.

[image]

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please read the screenshot you posted above with care. `Shift+Return` is not used for running the current **line** and advance, but to run the current **cell** and advance to the next one. If you don't know what a cell is in Spyder, you can read about it [here](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/editor.html#defining-code-cells).

Comment: Thank you.  I did not know what a cell was.  I thought cell and line were synonymous.  If you post this as an answer (and perhaps suggest using run selection to execute a single line), I will mark as correct.  Appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi Carlos.  When I try to change the 'run selection' key bindings to 'Shift+Return' (to mirror R), I get a message 'Forbidden key sequence! Shortcuts that use Shift and another key are unsupported.  Anything that I am doing wrong???

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong. The message is quite clear, please read it with care again.

Comment: So it really doesn't allow you to assign keybindings with shift??  Why would it limit shifts?  Any chance of changing this in the future?

Comment: Why would it support shift in default keybindings and then not allow you to change them?

Comment: Because it is hard-coded in our code, and that allows us to assign to "run cell", but not to anything else.

Comment: And any chance to change this in the future?  It seems quite limiting.  A lot of people move from R to python where shift+return is used to run a line of code in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Spyder maintainer here) Please read the screenshot you posted above with care. `Shift+Return` is not used for running the current line and advance, but to run the current cell and advance to the next one. If you don't know what a cell is in Spyder, you can read about it [here](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/editor.html#defining-code-cells).

To run lines, you need to use the shortcut named "run selection".